# Can armhf compiled software run on armel os?

Tags: ffmpeg

I am setting up my media server on my raspberry pi 3 (armv7) using docker. I downloaded a image of a media server and installed it, the problem is that image uses Opensuse and if I run dpkg --print-architecture it says its armel.

The problem comes to ffmpeg. The ffmpeg (https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/) armhf version throws error on certain movies, while armel version works with all. BUT the armhf version works better and faster, so I really need it.

I want to know if this could be a architecture compatibily problem between os and library or is something different, so I can report to developers.

When I run the command that produces error on console it says:

```
Bus error (core dumped)
```

Answer (score 3):

The most widely used architecture name for the `armv7` instruction set is `armhf`.

See [this](https://www.debian.org/ports/arm/index.en.html), [this](https://wiki.debian.org/ArmHardFloatPort#Minimum_CPU_.26_FPU) and [this](https://www.debian.org/ports/arm/index.en.html).

`ffmpeg` has a build for `armhf` listed on the page you linked, your problem is the Linux distribution that is not supporting the new `armv7` instruction set, i am not an openSUSE specialist but you can give [this](https://en.opensuse.org/HCL:Raspberry_Pi2) guide a try, or of course change to another Linux distribution.